# Update the key value of a json field in mysql

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-8.0

I have the following json field

```
{
  "Covid-19Vaccine Staus": "Not vaccinated (intent to in the future)",
  "Date of last vaccine taken": "2021-08-09T00:00:00+04:00",
  "If vaccinated, Name of vaccination received": "Other WHO Approved vaccine"
}
```

What i would like to do is update the key description i.e. Covid-19 Vaccine Staus to Covid19VaccineStaus.

On doing a direct update to the field on mysql workbench it generates the following query,

```
UPDATE `my_json_table` SET `containerValue` = '{\"Covid19VaccineStaus\": \"Vaccinated\", \"Date of last vaccine taken\": \"2021-07-13T00:00:00+04:00\", \"If vaccinated, Name of vaccination received\": \"Pfizer-BioNTech\"}' WHERE (`id` = '94');
```

where it looks like it takes the entire values for the field and then does the update.

What should the query look like if i want to update just the *Covid19VaccineStatus* key without putting in the values for the other data points for the json schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at [JSON functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-function-reference.html)

`JSON_REPLACE`,

> Replace values in JSON document

`JSON_REMOVE`,

> Remove data from JSON document

`JSON_INSERT`

> Insert data into JSON document

```
UPDATE `my_json_table` SET `containerValue` = JSON_REPLACE(`containerValue`, '$."Covid-19Vaccine Staus"', 'Vaccinated') WHERE (`id` = '94');

UPDATE `my_json_table` SET `containerValue` = JSON_REMOVE(`containerValue`, '$."Covid-19Vaccine Staus"') WHERE (`id` = '94');

UPDATE `my_json_table` SET `containerValue` = JSON_INSERT(`containerValue`, '$."Covid-19Vaccine Staus"', 'Vaccinated') WHERE (`id` = '94');
```

To replace a key and keep value

```
UPDATE `my_json_table` 
SET `containerValue` = 
    JSON_REMOVE(
        JSON_INSERT(`containerValue`, '$."Covid19VaccineStaus"', 
            JSON_EXTRACT(`containerValue`, '$."Covid-19Vaccine Staus"')), 
        '$."Covid-19Vaccine Staus"') 
WHERE (`id` = '94');
```

Comment: Thank you. So in my case i would have to use the JSON_REPLACE. But i see the value is required as well? I have multiple records where i need to change the key only.

Comment: @Bisoux `JSON_REPLACE` is to replace values, do you mean to change key and the respective value remains as it is?

Comment: Exactly, yes that is what i hope to do. Right now i am having to go and manually update the key value one by one on the field

Comment: Let me update answer to add this use case

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-set) which handles both insert and update actions.

```
UPDATE my_json_table
SET containerValue = JSON_SET(containerValue, '$."Covid-19Vaccine Staus"', 'Vaccinated')
WHERE id = 94;
```

So if your key does not exist yet in your JSON, it will be inserted with the value `Vaccinated`. Otherwise, the value corresponding to your key will be updated.

You can also find examples [here](https://database.guide/json_set-insert-or-update-values-in-a-json-document-in-mysql/) on how to handle arrays or multiple values with `JSON_SET`.

If you only need to update the value but not perform any insertion in your JSON if the key does not exist, you can use [JSON_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-replace).

If you only need to insert the key and the value but not perform any update in your JSON if the key already exists, you can use [JSON_INSERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-insert).

If you want to update the name of your key:

```
UPDATE my_json_table
SET containerValue = JSON_INSERT(
   JSON_REMOVE(containerValue, '$."Covid-19Vaccine Staus"'),
   '$.Covid19VaccineStaus',
   JSON_EXTRACT(containerValue, '$."Covid-19Vaccine Staus"')
)
WHERE id = 94;
```